# Прерывание обновления модели В vs2019 .net framework 4.72 ef5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Пытаюсь обновить модель, но после обновления ссыпаются сотнями ошибки типа:

> Ошибка    CS1061  "Model" не содержит определения "DeleteObject", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "DeleteObject", принимающий тип "ModelEntities" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Я посмотрел авто заполняемые файлы модели, там многие стали пустыми после обновления.
И такое регулярно возникает, на некоторые изменения обновляется нормально а на некоторые такое.

В связи с этим вопрос: где можно увидеть какая произошла ошибка во время обновления модели?
И почему вообще такое происходит?
А то получается я произвожу действие которые обрывается на ходу и я не могу понять почему это произошло чтобы исправить.

Стратегия создания кода Т4.

Comment: ef5 - это старая версия? Тогда почему метка `entity-framework-core`. Уточните, какая именно у вас версия.

Comment: да старая, другой метки не дыло по тому эту поставил, но думаю разницы большой не должно быть ибо тут как я понимаю проблема в самой студии а не версии фреймворка

Comment: Боюсь, что мало кто сможет помочь. Придётся искать решение проблемы в старых темах. Например: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18127633/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю может кому поможет, проблема была в том что при изменении параметров функции БД Студия не видит это и пытается построить зависимости по той схеме что была ранее а так как это не получается прерывает работу. Причём это не правят из версии к версии, такая ошибка присутствует и в последней версии на данный момент.

Но Решение простое, хоть и костыль: нужно временно удалить функцию или переименовать и запустить обновление модели, а затем вернуть обратно как было и запустить заново. Возможно есть более изящное решение, но у меня получилось такое, а так как параметры процедур и функций меняются достаточно редко то и иные решения я искать не стал, если кто найдёт лучшее решение пишите в комментариях к данному ответу. я все их читаю.